# How to embed a url/page redirection script to a closing pop up window

Tags: javascript

Please am making use of this script bellow to execute a pop up window when the close button is clicked on but i want to add an extra script that will help me open a new url/page when the "OK" button is clicked please can anyone help me out, here is the javascript am using:

```
<script language="Javascript"> 
    var needToConfirm = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit(){
        if (needToConfirm){
            my_window = window.open ("1.html","mywindow1","status=1,width=350,height=150");
           return "You have attempted to leave this page. If you have made any changes "
          +"to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be "
          +"lost. Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want to add an extra script that will help me open a new url/page when the "OK" button is clicked

That is by definition not possible. If the user confirms they want to leave the page, the page has no way of doing anything any more. It's a security feature to prevent sites that get closed from spamming the user with new windows.

Comment: As he says, what you want to do is specifically prohibited.

Answer (score -1):

looks like you want the parent (the opener) window to reload / load a page?
here is an example how to do this:
http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-refreshing.php